# How do I use Iron Sights on a laptop in Modern Combat 5?

Tags: keyboard, modern-combat-5

I just got a new laptop and downloaded Modern Combat 5: Blackout on it. I'm trying to figure out how to zoom/aim in the game. I don't have a mouse just a basic laptop setup w/ a mouse pad. Can somebody help me please??

Comment: “I don't have a mouse” that is problem 1, you really should get a mouse.

Answer (score 0):

1. You probably need a proper mouse to play the game effectively. Or a joypad controller. However even with a mouse pad you should be able to right click on the mouse pad, and look down the sights.
2. https://moderncombat.fandom.com/wiki/Modern_Combat_5:_Blackout_controls "Controls can be mapped to specific keys via the options menu." A lot of PC games have the ability to remap the keys as needed. So you should be able to change the key bindings from the mouse to one of the available keys on your keyboard. You might even be able to remap the mouse controls for looking around to the up down left right arrow keys, which might be more effective than trying to use a touchpad.